# Testing Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Currently I'm trying to write feature tests for laravel nova that assert that the page is loaded correctly and data can be seen.

However when I write the tests I can't find a way to assert that the correct text is shown due to way laravel nova's data is produce. Ontop of that I can't seem to test if a page loads correctly with laravel nova's 404 page coming back as a 200 response when a resource page that doesn't exist loads.

Has anyone found a good way to feature test nova?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*TL;DR: check out this repo: https://github.com/bradenkeith/testing-nova. It has helped me find my way on how to test Laravel Nova.*

Laravel Nova is basically a CRUD framework. So I'm assuming that, when you say

> "that the page is loaded correctly and data can be seen"

You actually mean: my resources are loaded correctly. Or, I can create/update/delete a resource. This is because Nova is loading its resource info asynchronous via api calls. 
So that's why, a good method to test your logic **is to test the `/nova-api/` routes**.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Nova;

use App\Note;
use Tests\TestCase;

class NoteTest extends TestCase
{
  public function setUp(): void
  {
    parent::setUp();
  }

  /** @test */
  public function it_gets_a_note()
  {
    // given 
    $note = factory(Note::class)->create();

    $response = $this->get('/nova-api/notes/' . $note->id)
      ->assertStatus(200)
      ->assertJson([
        'resource'  =>  [
          'id'    =>  [
            'value' =>  $note->id
          ]
        ]
    ]);
  }
}
```

By calling the route `https://my-app.test/resources/notes/1`, we can assert that we're getting a 200 response (successful) and that we're actually returning our newly created Note. This is a pretty trustworthy test to be sure a resource detail page is working fine.

If, however, you are talking about *Browser Testing*, you might want to take a look at [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/dusk):

> Laravel Dusk provides an expressive, easy-to-use browser automation and testing API.

Once installed, you can start real browser testing:

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$user->assignRole('admin');

$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
  $browser
    ->loginAs($user)
    ->visit('/')
    ->assertSee('Dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue, I found out that the gate in App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider.php is not letting users pass, just return true **when testing only** and everything must work as expected

```
    protected function gate()
{
    Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {

        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: This would allow any user to use the Nova dashboard. That could end up being very bad if it makes it to production.

Better alternatives could be overriding this gate in a test (possibly from `setUp`?), or simply creating a `User` with proper permissions and acting as it using `$this->actingAs`, as done in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897472

Answer (score -11):

Add on app/config file in your project directory:

```
App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider::class,
```